# monkeyrunner as REPL?

Tags: android, python, jython, monkeyrunner

#### Question

Given that by running `monkeyrunner` without arguments it starts a REPL session where I can use monkey runner python classes and modules.

Is there a way to also load a python class in there and test that class using the REPL?

#### What I tried

I've tried [reading the manual](https://developer.android.com/studio/test/monkeyrunner/index.html) but other than saying that there are command line flags/options it doesn't list them anywhere that I can see.

Running `man monkeyrunner` doesn't yield any reference manual. Nor does `monkeyrunner -help` or `monkeyrunner -h` or `monkeyrunner --help`.

I've tried `cd`ing myself into the folder with the `abc.py` file, but `import abc` on the `monkeyrunner` REPL doesn't load the module by giving a `ImportError: No module named abc`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Be sure the path to your module is in `sys.path`. IIRC `monkeyrunner` does not honor `PYTHONPATH`.

Alternatively, you can use [AndroidViewClient/culebra](https://github.com/dtmilano/AndroidViewClient) as a replacement and you will be able to do from `python`. Assuming there's a `mod.py` on your current directory:

```
$ python -i
Python 2.7.12 (default, Nov 19 2016, 06:48:10) 
[GCC 5.4.0 20160609] on linux2
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import com.dtmilano.android.viewclient
>>> import mod
I'm mod
>>>
```